# defining a macro with variables

Tags: c++

I am working on Marlin 3D program. I made some changes for xyz prop and I do not make a definition as `#define PRB_GCODE_END "G92 X-" XOFF "Y" XOFF "Z" ZOFF "\ n"` to send the final xyz coordinates as gcode at the end of the promulgation procedure. It is required. If anyone has any idea how to use float type variables during macro definition please help.

```cpp
void _user_gcode_exe(const char * const cmd) {
  lcd_return_to_status();
  enqueue_and_echo_commands_P(cmd);
}
 
void user_gcode_exe_1() { 
  float XOFF = (25.00 + PRB_XOFFSET + (TOOL_DIA / 2.00));
  float YOFF = (25.00 - (PRB_YOFFSET + (TOOL_DIA / 2.00)));
  float ZOFF = (10.00 + PRB_ZOFFSET);
  
#define PRB_GCODE_END "G92 X-" XOFF " Y" XOFF " Z" ZOFF "\n"
    
#define PRB_GCODE "M117 Z-XY Probing now..\nG38.2 F120 Z-20.00\nG92 X0.00 Y.00 Z0.00\nG0 Z5.00 F1200\nG0 X-20.00 F1200\nG0 Z-5.00 F1200\nG38.2 F120 X25.00\nG92 X0.00\nG0 X-5.00 Y-25.00 F1200\nG0 X15.00 F1200\nG38.2 F120 Y25.00\nG92 Y0.00\nG0 Y-5.00 F1200\nG0 Z10.00 F1200\nG0 X-25.00 Y25.00 F1200\n"
  
#define MSG__OK "M117 Z-XY Probing done..\n"   
  _user_gcode_exe(PSTR(PRB_GCODE PRB_GCODE_END MSG__OK)); 
}
```

While defining `PRB_GCODE_END`, ensuring that float type variables are included in this definition. For example: Considering that the variables `XOFF`, `YOFF` and `ZOFF` are calculated as 12.85, 11.25 and 10.50 respectively. `PRB_GCODE_END` should occur as follows:
`G92 X-12.85 Y 11.25 Z10.50 \n`

Comment: why are you asking a c++ programming question at an arduino site? ... how is your question related to the arduino?

Comment: this program is running on arduino mega

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Variables and macros are completely different concepts and handled by completely different parts of the compiler toolchain.

Instead you will need to build your string up into a char array (or whatever format the `_user_gcode_exec()` function accepts) with the likes of sprintf.